# how to pass parameters to controller from view

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-form-helper

I need to pass parameters from a view to control in a form. These parameters are for example a string that is not in a `textField`. The string is "FATHER" and I send this string from the view to the controller when I click on the submit button in the form. Anyone can suggest how I can do it?

Comment: What have you tried that's not working? You need to have hidden field in your form to post that value.

Comment: submit your code for better answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a hidden input field to your form with a value of "FATHER":

```
<?= form_hidden('name_of_field', 'FATHER') ?>
```

and in your controller, get the value when the form is submitted:

```
$value = $this->input->post('name_of_field');
```

Answer (score 0):

So if this question is about asp.net MVC ... :
Are you using a strongly typed view, do you have a ViewModel? If so, add a property of type string, say `StringToHide`, to it, set it to "FATHER" and then, in your form, add

```
@Html.HiddenFor(StringToHide)
```

Then the information will be passed to the controller, but it is not editable by the user. And if you're not using a viewmodel yet, well, then you should. It's a clean way to compose all your data when passing from views to controllers and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Asp.net MVC

In View

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("Menu", "", new { parameterFromView= "FATHER" }); }
```

In Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Menu(string parameterFromView)
{
    // do whatever
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In jquery call append the text Father to the URL and accept it in controller.
see code below.

```
$("#submit").click(funtion(){
   window.url = "Controller/Action/" + "Father";
});
```